# Data is not filling in dataview

Tags: asp.net, datatable, repeater, dataview

I am trying to bind my repeater with dataview but it is not showing me data in dataview when i see it through breakpoint

```
 private void Get_Data()
    {
        String File = Server.MapPath("BlogContent.xml");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(File);

    DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
        DataTable dt = dv.Table;
        ViewState.Add("Mytable", dt);

    }

    private void Bind_Data(int take, int pageSize)
    {
        PagedDataSource page = new PagedDataSource();
        page.AllowCustomPaging = true;
        page.AllowPaging = true;
        DataTable dtv = (DataTable)ViewState["Mytable"];
        DataView dv = new DataView();
        dv = dtv.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = "id>=" + pageSize + " AND " + "id<=" + take;
        page.DataSource = dv;
        page.PageSize = psize;
        Repeater1.DataSource = page;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            int rowcount = dtv.Rows.Count;
            CreatePagingControl(rowcount);
        }

    }   

 PagedDataSource page = new PagedDataSource();
            page.AllowCustomPaging = true;
            page.AllowPaging = true;
            DataTable dtv = (DataTable)ViewState["Mytable"];
            DataView dv = new DataView();
            dv = dtv.DefaultView;
            dv.RowFilter = "id>=" + pageSize + " AND " + "id<=" + take;
            page.DataSource = dv;
            page.PageSize = psize;
            Repeater1.DataSource = page;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                int rowcount = dtv.Rows.Count;
                CreatePagingControl(rowcount);
            }
```

please check it and tell me where i am going wrong.. I try to add paging in repeater control the number of paging display well but data is not fetching in dataview . When i check my datatable it is filling but when it comes to dataview shows me nothng

Comment: Is this line wrong: 

DataTable dt = dv.Table; Shouldn't it be DataTable dt = dv.ToTable; ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answers.. The order of id in my xml was not in correct In my xml the id of each node is like

5
3
4
1
2

I do it correct 
1
2
3
4
5

and it is working now ....